# Angular & Spring user verification

Tags: mysql, angular, spring

I want to implement an email and phone number verification. whenever new user register/signup. I am using Angular from front-end and spring boot from back-end. what is the best approach to achieve that and How?

sending and verifying one time password code to registered email and phone number for user verification

Comment: first you need to implement authentication in sprintboot/any rest framework once that is done then u need to use http interceptor in angular to implement the security. start here https://angular.io/api/common/http/HttpInterceptor.  here is the angular #jwt example https://medium.com/@ryanchenkie_40935/angular-authentication-using-the-http-client-and-http-interceptors-2f9d1540eb8

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.